# How to scroll down on Appium when you have multi plages to go down?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, mobile, appium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRNWr.png)

How do I scroll down when you have multiple pages. On the third page bottom there is a link but when I use driver.scrollTo();, it skips it goes back to first page.

Answer (score 1):

you can use JavaScriptExecutor for scrolling
i have created below method for scrolling it is working fine in iOS but have not tested for Android

```
public static void swipe(AppiumDriver<?> driver,String sDirection, int iCount)

{
    while(iCount>0)
    {
        HashMap<String,String> swipeObject=new HashMap<String,String>();
        swipeObject.put("direction", sDirection);

        JavascriptExecutor jsDriver=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;

        jsDriver.executeScript("mobile:scroll", swipeObject);
        iCount--;

    }
}
```

hope it might help :)

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how would look with Java.

Answer (score 0):

this is java code, and it should work fine for scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

try driver.swipe method

Visit this link

https://automationbyharsh.blogspot.in/2017/01/how-driverswipe-works-on-ios.html